# How can you access the constant variables of one Component in another Component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am working on React Table. I am basically a beginner in React. I have a dashboard page where I display a React Table of 8 columns. I have a customize button which will open a popup page, this popup page has 8 check boxes allows me to show/hide those React columns. Initially all the check boxes in this popup page is set to true. When I uncheck a column that particular column get disabled.

There are images in the end to see what I am trying to do.

I will be using this logic for show hide columns (this question was asked by me two days back) - [You can see how this is done using a React Table attribute/property called show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638095/how-to-show-and-hide-some-columns-on-react-table). When show is true that column/sub column is shown and When show is false that column/sub column is hidden.

The React Table data is like this

```
const columns = [
 {
    Header: 'Column 1',
    accessor: 'firstName',
    // show: true // shows the particular column (true is default)
   //  show: false // hides the particular column
  },
  {
    Header: 'Column 2',
    accessor: 'firstName',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Column 3',
    accessor: 'firstName',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Column 4',
    accessor: 'firstName',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Column 5',
    accessor: 'firstName',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Column 6',
    accessor: 'firstName',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Column 7',
    accessor: 'firstName'
  },
  {
    Header: 'Column 8',
    accessor: 'firstName',
  }
];
```

Now have a look at this image. The image shows my dashboard page along with the checkbox popup page which can turn my column on/off (or show/hide)

[image: Image of dashboard and checkbox page]

This is the code for the popup page for checkbox

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ActionCreators } from '../../../actions';
import ButtonComponent from '../../common/button/ButtonComponent';
import { CheckBox } from '../../common/chkbox/CheckBox';

class CustomizedView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCheckChildElement = this.handleCheckChildElement.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { id: 1, value: 'Column 1', isChecked: true },
        { id: 2, value: 'Column 2', isChecked: true },
        { id: 3, value: 'Column 3', isChecked: true },
        { id: 4, value: 'Column 4', isChecked: true },
        { id: 5, value: 'Column 5', isChecked: true },
        { id: 6, value: 'Column 6', isChecked: true },
        { id: 7, value: 'Column 7', isChecked: true },
        { id: 8, value: 'Column 8', isChecked: true },
      ]
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ isChecked: !this.state.isChecked });
  }

  handleCheckChildElement(event) {
    const { items } = this.state; //extract state values like this to a const variable
    const newItems = items.map((item) => { //do map on items because map returns a new array. It’s good practice to use .map than forEach in your case
      if(item.value === event.target.value) {
        item.isChecked = event.target.checked;
        return item; //return updated item object so that it will be pushed to the newItems array
      }
      return item; // return item because you need this item object as well
    });
    this.setState({ items: newItems }); //finally set newItems array into items
    const column1checked = items[0].isChecked;
    console.log('column1checked ' + column1checked);
    const column2checked = items[1].isChecked;
    console.log('column2checked ' + column2checked);
    const column3checked = items[2].isChecked;
    console.log('column3checked ' + column3checked);
    const column4checked = items[3].isChecked;
    console.log('column4checked ' + column4checked);
    const column5checked = items[4].isChecked;
    console.log('column5checked ' + column5checked);
    const column6checked = items[5].isChecked;
    console.log('column6checked ' + column6checked);
    const column7checked = items[6].isChecked;
    console.log('column7checked ' + column7checked);
    const column8checked = items[7].isChecked;
    console.log('column8checked ' + column8checked);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='div-container-custom' >
        <div className='bottomBar'>
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Apply'
            className='activeButton filterMargin-custom'
            width='100'
            display='inline-block'
            onClick={() => { this.props.applyFilter(this.state, false); }}
          />
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Clear Filter'
            className='greyedButton clear-custom-filter'
            width='100'
            display='block'
            marginTop='60'
            onClick={() => { this.props.applyFilter(this.state, true); }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className='data-points-text'>
            <span> Columns </span>
          </div>
          <div className="App">
            <ul>
              {
                this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
                  return (<div key={i} ><CheckBox handleCheckChildElement={this.handleCheckChildElement} {...item} /></div>);
                })
              };
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CustomizedView.propTypes = {
  applyFilter: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

CustomizedView.defaultProps = {
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomizedView);
```

Now my point is when I only uncheck 4th column in the checkbox popup page I get the desired values (the above code)

```
column1checked true
column2checked true
column3checked true
column4checked false
column5checked true
column6checked true
column7checked true
column8checked true
```

And ultimately this is my checkbox page

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const CheckBox = (props) => {
  // super(props);
  return (
    <li>
      <input key={props.id} onClick={props.handleCheckChildElement} type="checkbox" checked={props.isChecked} value={props.value} /> {props.value}
    </li>
  );
};

CheckBox.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  handleCheckChildElement: PropTypes.func,
  isChecked: PropTypes.bool,
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

export default CheckBox;
```

Now my question is I have the constants in CustomizedView Component. I need those const variables available in ReactTable Component (path is like this - '../../common/chkbox/CheckBox')

In the main dashboard page I import the React Table

```
import ReactTableComponent from '../common/react_table/ReactTableComponent';
```

and just use it in the render function of the main dashboard page in this way.

```
<ReactTableComponent />
```

So I need to use all those const variables of Customized variables in ReactTable Component to show/hide tables.

Also here I have to use show: some_const  (I cannot use true or false)

**I am a complete beginner in React and I need help from this community. Kindly help to implement this idea.**

**All I want to know the best/easiest (may be great way or dumb way) way to transfer those 8 const variables from components\abcdashboard\customized_view\Customizedview to components\common\react_table\ReactTableComponent**

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when you want to share data across components like this, what you want is to consolidate the data in a higher-up component, and use functions to modify it.

Here's a contrived example (CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6w5lppv53n)):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Bill"
  };

  changeName = name => {
    this.setState({ name });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>name is: {this.state.name}</h1>
        <ChildA changeName={this.changeName} />
        <ChildB changeName={this.changeName} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class ChildA extends React.Component {
  state = {
    nameA: "Steve"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.props.changeName(this.state.nameA)}>
        change to my name
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class ChildB extends React.Component {
  state = {
    nameB: "Elon"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.props.changeName(this.state.nameB)}>
        change to my name
      </button>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

Here, the `Parent` can access the value of the names of the children through the `changeName` function which is passed down.

If you just want to share variables and not data per se, you could just define a whole file and export various variables like:

```
export const PI = 3.14
```

and so on, then do like:

```
import { PI } from './variables'
```

in other files, for example.

Comment: Any other solution apart from React Fragments ?

Comment: You can basically view React Fragments as divs, so they don't change anything in my answer here.

Comment: I am a complete beginner in React. Can you suggest the best way to transfer those 8 const variables from components\abcdashboard\customized_view\Customizedview to components\common\react_table\ReactTableComponent

Comment: Since they're part of state, then the easiest way to do it is to pass a function from `ReactTableComponent` to `CustomizedView`.

Comment: Please show me how as I am completely new to React.

Comment: are you there? Please reply to me