# How to hide radio buttons in reactable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

How can I remove the column of radio buttons from a reactable table in my Shiny app, but keeping the `selection = "single"` argument?

My reprex is based on this [solution](https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/83) to hiding the all/none checkbox with `selection = "multiple"`, I was hoping that I could do something similar to remove the radio buttons.

[image: table]

`app.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  includeCSS("hide_radio.css"),
  titlePanel("Hide radio buttons"),
  mainPanel(reactableOutput("table"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderReactable({
      reactable(
        mtcars,
        selection = "single",
        columns = list(
          .selection = colDef(
            headerStyle = list(pointerEvents = "none")
          )
        ),
        theme = reactableTheme(
        headerStyle = list("& input[type='checkbox']" = list(display = "none"))
        )
      )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`hide_radio.css`:

```
.hide-checkbox {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hide-checkbox input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** If you want to hide the entire column (not only the elements) there is a much simpler way:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hide radio buttons"),
  mainPanel(reactableOutput("table"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      mtcars,
      selection = "single",
      columns = list(
        # mpg  = colDef(show = FALSE),
        .selection = colDef(show = FALSE)
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this procedure needs to be adapted once the underlying [react table library is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53638202/9841389) in the R package:

> The column property *show* is deprecated. Use initialstate.hiddenColumns
> instead.

Check: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1804

---

**Initial answer**: Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
            .hide-checkbox {
              pointer-events: none;
            }
            .hide-checkbox input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
              display: none !important;
            }
           ")
    )
  ),
  titlePanel("Hide radio buttons"),
  mainPanel(reactableOutput("table"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      mtcars,
      selection = "single",
      columns = list(
        .selection = colDef(
          headerClass = "hide-checkbox"
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's awesome! Is it possible to to remove the white space as well?